# ignore files in use (being written to) when using rsync

Tags: rsync

I have an SFTP server where clients are constantly uploading large files. On a periodic basis, I want to copy all *complete* (fully uploaded) files to another machine for processing. I don't want to copy a file that is actively being written to. Is there a way to accomplish that? I am currently using rsync but I am open to switching to something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if a file is currently open (if a file is currently written is for sure open by some process) the standard way is to use `lsof`:

```
if lsof /your/file > /dev/null; then echo "file currently open"; fi
```

You can use this snippet to filter find results for only not opened files and use them to feed rsync:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'if ! lsof `readlink -f {}` > /dev/null; then echo `basename {}`; fi' \; | tr '\n' '\0' | rsync -avz --from0 --files-from=- ./ user@host:destination/
```

Some notes:

- `readlink -f` is needed to have full path of a file, lsof accept only full path
- `tr '\n' '\0'` emulate find `-print0`

Comment: Where I specify the path to rsync ?

Comment: The last part of the command: `user@host:destination` to rsync to a remote path or simply `destination` to rsync to a local path.

Comment: any way to get relative path ?

Answer (score 1):

One challenge here is to determine whether the files are still begin written to. There is no perfect way to do this. I think the best you can do is to simply check the last-modified timestamp on the files, and only copy those files that have not been modified for a few minutes.

`rsync` by itself cannot do this, but you can combine it with the [find-command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

```
cd /path/to/directory/with/files
find ./ -type f -mmin +5 -print0 | rsync --archive --verbose --from0 --files-from=- ./ yourotherserver:targetdir/
```

To break down this command, it does two things:

1. It uses `find ./ -type f -mmin +5 -print0` to identify all files that haven't been modified for at least 5 minutes.
2. It then feeds this list into `rsync` using the `--from0` and `--files-from` parameters. This will make `rsync` only consider those files that `find` has identified.